# Execute External commands Fitnesse/DBFit from within a Test page

Tags: testing, ssh, db2, fitnesse, dbfit

I would like to execute external commands in my test from Fitnesse/DBFit from within a Test page.

For example, as part of a Unit Test:

1. run a remote ssh command towards host ABC and copy a file with win cp command
2. run a DB2 load command to import the data in the database from the file
3. run a stored procedure
4. verify results

May anyone advice regarding step 1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's been a few implementations of a `CommandLineFixture` - google commandlinefixture and you'll find them.

Comment: Thanks, may you kindly point one that works and where the code is available to download and use?

Comment: I haven't used a CommandLineFixture - hopefully someone else with experience can help.

Comment: I got the java code from http://fit.c2.com/files/CommandLineFixture/CommandLineFixture.java compiled it, created a Jar and put in the Fitnesse lib directory. then it works.